# Erro quando o usuário fornece o nome do arquivo

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    int caracteres = 0;
    int linhas = 0;
    int imprimiveis = 0;


    FILE *arquivo;
    char nome[50];

    printf("Escreva o nome do arquivo: ");
    fgets(nome, 50, arquivo);

    arquivo = fopen(nome,"r");
    if (arquivo == NULL)
    {   
        printf("Erro, arquivo nao existe.");
    }
    else
    {
        while((ch = fgetc(arquivo))!= EOF)
        {
            caracteres++;
            if (ch != '\n')
            {
                imprimiveis++;
            }
            else if(ch == '\n')
            {
                linhas++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);

    printf("Numero de caracteres lidos: %d\n",caracteres);
    printf("número de caracteres imprimíveis lidos: %d\n",imprimiveis);
    printf("número de linhas: %d\n",linhas);
}
```

Quero saber como faz pro usuário escolher o nome do arquivo. Tentei fazer assim, mas está dando falha de segmentação. O que há de errado?

Comment: Tá, legal o código. Qual é a sua pergunta?

Comment: Quero saber como faz pro usuario escolher o nome do arquivo.Tentei fazer assim mas ta dando falha de segmentaçao

Comment: Note que a função fgets coloca o caractere fim de linha (\n) na string lida sempre que não alcança o limite de caracteres, assim você deve substituir este último \n por \0.

Answer (score 1):

O erro está aqui:

```
    fgets(nome, 50, arquivo);
```

Neste ponto, `arquivo` não é um ponteiro com um conteúdo válido. O que você queria é isso:

```
    fgets(nome, 50, stdin);
```

Comment: verdade, tinha equecido essa. Mas, continua dando o mesmo erro. Agora que eu n sei dizer mesmo porque.Agradeço pelo outro comentario.

Comment: `fgets()` não remove o `\n` do final da linha lida. `fopen()` vai falhar se o nome do arquivo apresentar `\n` no final!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `isprint()` da biblioteca padrão `ctype.h` para testar se um caractere é imprimível.

A função `fgets()` não remove o `\n` do final da *string* lida, e `fopen()` vai falhar se o nome do arquivo possuir `\n` no final. Que tal usar `scanf()` no lugar de `fgets()` para evitar essa complicação ?

Veja só seu código reescrito:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    int caracteres = 0;
    int linhas = 0;
    int imprimiveis = 0;
    FILE *arquivo = NULL;
    char nome[ PATH_MAX + 1 ];
    char linha[ PATH_MAX + 1 ];

    printf("Escreva o nome do arquivo: ");
    scanf( "%s", nome );

    arquivo = fopen( nome,"r" );

    if( arquivo == NULL )
    {
        printf("Erro, arquivo '%s' nao existe.\n", nome );
        return 1;
    }

    while( fgets( linha, PATH_MAX, arquivo ) )
    {
        i = 0;

        while( linha[i] )
        {
            if( isprint(linha[i]) )
                imprimiveis++;

            i++;
        }

        caracteres += i;
        linhas++;
    }

    fclose(arquivo);

    printf("Caracteres lidos: %d\n", caracteres );
    printf("Caracteres imprimiveis lidos: %d\n", imprimiveis );
    printf("Numero de linhas lidas: %d\n", linhas );

    return 0;
}
```

Arquivo de Teste (`entrada.txt`):

```
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis
praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas
molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et
dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.
Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil
impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et
aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et
voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum
rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus
maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
```

Saída:

```
Escreva o nome do arquivo: entrada.txt
Caracteres lidos: 844
Caracteres imprimiveis lidos: 833
Numero de linhas lidas: 12
```

Comment: nossa! brigadao cara, ajudou demais!!!!